# Getting error in soap api call

Tags: soap-api, integration, soap

I am facing this error, when trying to pull the my external org's object details using soap:

> System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService
>   returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_TYPE: Unknown type:DeployMessage
>   faultcode=sf:INVALID_TYPE faultactor=

Comment: provide code snippet

Answer (score 0):

this [means](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm#i1421521)

> The specified sObject type is invalid.

Check API name of object. if it is custom object, than it should contain `__c` ending

Answer (score 0):

[DeployMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deployresult.htm#DeployMessage) is part of the [DeployDetails](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deployresult.htm#deploy_details) response that the Metadata API returns.

So it would appear you are trying to call the Soap based Metadata API from Apex. If so, are you using the existing [apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) library? It knows about DeployMessage.